# Is Ruby's net/http request visible to user?

Tags: ruby, firebug, net-http

I'm using Ruby's library for getting http pages (net/http), for example:

```
Net::HTTP.get URI.parse(uri)
```

Is this visible for user somehow? I mean, can the user use firebug (for example) to obtain `uri` or is this is only handled and visible by the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Net::HTTP requests are on the server running Ruby. The user cannot monitor those requests unless they had access to the server or the server's network.